# Use AuthFeature but disable SessionFeature?

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServiceStack service that is always sent a JWT every request, so it seems to me that I do not need a persistent session whatsoever.

How can I disable the SessionFeature yet keep the JwtAuthProviderReader which is currently working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [JWT Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) then the Session will be stateless and the [Session cookies](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) won't be used for storing sessions but is used as identifiers for other features such as [Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) or maintaining server user state in [Session Bags](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#typed-sessions-in-mvc).

But if you're not using any features using Session Cookies they can be removed with:

```cs
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AllowSessionCookies = false
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mythz, would there be any benefit in also removing the SessionFeature or is it pretty much benign with session cookies disabled?

Comment: @JanMartin There's no benefit, but you can prevent AuthFeature from registering it by clearing it from `AuthFeature.RegisterPlugins`